# PHP header redirect working in nginx even output sent

Tags: php, nginx, php5, php-fpm

*note: There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037199/php-header-location-works-in-the-middle-of-html) but that's about Apache.*

The following code

```
<?php
echo '.';
header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com');
```

is fully 'working' under nginx 0.7.67 where 'working' means the php redirect is working fine without errors in the error log or displaying the `.`.

How can i force nginx or php-fpm to throw the `PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check value of `output_buffering` parameter in your php.ini file.

[php.ini #output-buffering](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering)

Comment: Thank you, it's totally my fault. There's a framework on two different servers (Apache/nginx) and i thought there's something with nginx so i didn't checked my php.ini :( Thank you, again!

Comment: What's the "answer" here? In this case, should it be turned off? on? enlarged?

Comment: @Ciabaros it should be ON to prevent the error in question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found that it was because a `header("Status: 200 OK", false, 200);` before the header to redirect. So I added a condition not to display the header 200 if I know that I will have to redirect:

```
if(!isset($_GET['utm_source'])) { //Header will be Redirect 301 from global_cookies.inc.php
    header("Status: 200 OK", false, 200);
}
```

**Note**: With Apache I had not this problem and could redirect even after a header 200.